# Access container environment variables in inline run command

Tags: bash, docker

The task is very simple, I know an environment variable is (will be) set inside container and I want to use it in my inline run command. However the value does not get populated:

```
docker run --rm --link other ubuntu printenv | grep OTHER_ENV_VAR_NAME && echo ${OTHER_ENV_VAR_NAME}
```

current output of above command is:

```
> OTHER_ENV_VAR_NAME=valueOfVariableInLinkedContainer
>
```

the output of `echo` on second line is empty. what I expect to get is:

```
> OTHER_ENV_VAR_NAME=valueOfVariableInLinkedContainer
> valueOfVariableInLinkedContainer
```

the `printenv` gives the right value but the value passed to `echo` is not correct. I suggest that value is being evaluated on my host and not inside the container. Therefore I tried to use single and double quotes around echo command and to escape the `$` using `\` with no success.

My host machine is also an Ubuntu.

Comment: `value passed to echo is not correct`, whats wrong with it? Please post your expected output and what is actually output, and also the output of your first command.

Comment: included current and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to pipe and echo inside the same CMD of a docker run, use a shell command (`sh -c`)

```
docker run --rm --link other ubuntu sh -c 'printenv | grep OTHER_ENV_VAR_NAME && echo ${OTHER_ENV_VAR_NAME}'
```

If you don't, the pipe grep and the echo would take place in your *host* shell (the one where `docker run` is executed).
That would not echo anything, since the environment value is only set within the docker session.

Comment: with and without `-it`, grep works but not the echo and thats my problem.

Comment: @mohamnag that is completely normal: just grepping the value has no effect on the current shell.

Comment: grep is there just for testing purposes, what I need is to get value in my echo command. echo will be replaced with other command but what I need is the value of it. something like `docker run --rm -it --link other ubuntu tar ${OTHER_ENV_VAR_NAME}`

Comment: thanks but I dont want (can) to export value to host, I just want to use it in run command.

Comment: @mohamnag my point is: what the `docker run` shell outputs has no influence in your shell. If you don't set that value in your host shell, that host shell won't be able to echo anything.

Comment: but the echo is running inside container (and it should stay like that)

Comment: @mohamnag "but the echo is running inside container ": uh... no. I have rewritten my answer in order to propose a solution where the grep and the echo would be part of the *docker* shell session (and not the host one)